# Cordova Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone: Open External PDF URL

Tags: javascript, pdf, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cordova

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application using HTML5 and JavaScript through PhoneGap. Within the application, there is a list of items that links to an URL to a PDF document. The app need to open the URL on tap event.

For some reason, the JavaScript window.open(...) will not do anything. The tap event is triggered correctly, because I could alert message the correct URL.

Am I missing anything? Or it is not possible to open external URL in Windows Phone 8 app?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express with Windows Phone SDK 8.0. The Visual Studio has Cordova project plugin installed. Cordova version: 2.6.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the browser component of Windows Phone 8 is incapable of reading PDF files. There's no way to direct the target/default app to open PDF URLs.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/F--ChxSc_6A